# Как запустить проект, написанный в Eclipse на IDEA?

Tags: eclipse, android, java, intellij-idea

Как запустить проект, написанный в Eclipse на IDEA?
Что нужно нажать в IDEA? Импорт или опен, или что там?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно выбрать <kbd>Import Project</kbd>.

Только будьте осторожны: студия может перевести ваш проект на Gradle. Обычно это происходит, когда вы выбираете саму папку проекта, а не верхнюю, т.е. если вы выберите папку `Project` в такой, например, иерархии:   `AndroidStudioProjects/ProjectName/Project/src/`

Если же выбрать `ProjectName`, то студия может попросить выбрать, из какого сборщика делать импорт, и, по идее, на Gradle перехода не будет.

Comment: @DroidAlex, а как добавить в IDEA этот тот же самый Android Studio либу отсюда https://github.com/OlegKunitsyn/libshout-java ? Сам проект мой создан без градие всяких, а простой, обычный... А ссылка эта, я как понял, собрана на maven, так вот как мне добавить её?

Comment: Ну, это не классический для Gradle проект. Поэтому проще всего Вам просто скопировать исходники в свой проект. А вообще задумайтесь о переносе проекта на Gradle. Сможете в build.gradle просто добавить строку, например:
`compile: com.google.guava:16.0.1`, и не заморачиваться с установкой.